# Can't find a good enough html5 video player

Tags: html5-video, jwplayer, flowplayer, video-player

I've been on the search for html5 video players for well into 3 months trying virtually everything...

Right now my best choice is SublimeVideo as it seems to work the best, my only gripe is that when playing videos from my website over 3g/LTE data connections the videos will sometimes have trouble playing. The first 3 to 4 videos will run fine but after that it's hit and miss where 50 percent of the videos will give a connection error or not play at all..

I really have no idea as over wifi or via pc - it will work flawlessly.

I've tried jwplayer - wifi, 3g and desktop videos seem to load 75 percent of the time and freeze the rest.

I've tried flowplayer but that also is inconsistent and takes a long time to load videos in general. The three spinning circles for about 10 to 15 seconds before the video starts.

I've verified my server and everything seems fine on that end which is why it seems to work well via wifi and desktop? I'm guessing maybe there is an issue with concurrent connections over 3g? As it seems sublime does not close the video connection when it finishes it kind of leaves it where it left off..

any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: No video player script can compensate for a lousy connection. There is no magic.

Comment: Your saying that it's the connections fault and not the player, but why can I go to youtube and other video sites and play those videos without issue?

Answer (score 1):

If someone has a slow connection, you need to offer those users low quality streams. The JW Player offers dynamic (adaptive) bitrate switching for this exact purpose.

Comment: I've tried jwplayer but it seems to take longer to load than sublime - and the videos at times don't load period.. I'm not sure if this is an error on my end but I would be willing to pay if it can be resolved with jwplayer.

Comment: Well, can you provide a link to where you are running this? That would be a good starting point.

Comment: It`s an adult site - not sure if JWplayer has any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) it worked well for me